# Creating GroupID and ArtifactID for a custom Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am writing my own Grails Plugin. 
When I package it, I see a pom.xml and plugin.xml are generated.  In these, the `groupId` and `artifactId` are `org.grails.plugins` and `plugin-config` respectively.

I would like to specify what these should be so hat my plugin ends up in the correct place in artifactory.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the job of release plugin to set the default `groupId` for the plugin. For all grails plugin it is `org.grails.plugins`.

You can modify `groupId` by setting a property in plugin descriptor as:

```
class PluginDemoGrailsPLugin{

    //or def groupId = ...
    def group = "com.example.plugins"
    ......
}
```

The artifactId is chosen by convention as well. For example:

```
Project Name --> ArtifactId    --> Artifact Name
-----------------------------------------------------
PluginDemo   --> plugin-demo   --> grails-plugin-demo.zip
PluginConfig --> plugin-config --> grails-plugin-config.zip
```

I have not seen the `artifactId` being customized without integrating with build tools like Maven or Gradle. Using these build tools it is transparent as to how `groupId` and `artifactId` can be specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `groupId` and `version` in the *PluginConfig file like:

```
class PlayGrailsPlugin {
    def groupId = "com.example.project"
    def version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    ...
}
```

How you name the plugin config file has a BIG impact.

The 'artifactId' is taken from the plugin name.
For example if you have a plugin called **PlayGrailsPlugin** the artifactId will be "**play**".
If your plugin does not specify a groupId then this defaults to "org.grails.plugins".

Specifying `def artifactId = "play"` in your file **does not** matter.

More detail can be found [here](https://grails.org/plugin/maven-publisher)